# Is there a way to translate the owner field of an object?

Tags: translation

I am looking for a way to set a French translation for the `Owner` field for a custom object in a managed package (specifically the "Product Package" object in nCino, if that is relevant) as part of a work task.

I know the Owner field would be considered a standard field, so does this mean that there is no way to set a translation for it in a different language?

Comment: If you mean the field's label, then yes. This is translated in the same way you translate any other field label. If you mean the field's value, no, object name translations are not yet available.

Comment: @PhilW But the owner field is a standard field, so you cannot add translations for the field label in the translation workbench, which is where most of the translations are done. I want to know if there is someway to translate a standard field label like `Òwner`. I have searched and have not yet found any way to do so.

Comment: Try exporting the XLIF file for translation to see if you can find it there; I believe you will. I would have to check on how we translated it, but 99.9% sure we did, without issue.